# How to color every odd row of table that some row have rowspan

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to color every odd row of table with color blue but every first column doesn't have color. Some row have first column that have rowspan that take 2 or more row, so several row below that row have less `td` than row that have rowspan have. I want to color the table like the left table in the image but my css code result the right table in the image.

this is my code

```css
table,td {
  border:1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr:nth-child(odd),
td:first-child {
    background: cyan;
}

td:first-child {
    background: white;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">senin</td>
      <td>matematika</td>
      <td>pak A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>bahasa inggris</td>
      <td>pak B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>selasa</td>
      <td>ipa</td>
      <td>bu A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3">rabu</td>
      <td>fisika</td>
      <td>pak C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ekonomi</td>
      <td>bu B</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
      <td>sejarah</td>
      <td>bu C</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
<table>
```

this is the [table illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIBhF.png). How to color the table like the left table in the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Took me some time, but it could actually be really simple, if your goal is to exclude only the first column, you could just select the odd rows and the last two columns and set the background with this `tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-last-child(-n+2)` selector:

```css
table,td {
  border:1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-last-child(-n+2) {
    background: cyan;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">senin</td>
      <td>matematika</td>
      <td>pak A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>bahasa inggris</td>
      <td>pak B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>selasa</td>
      <td>ipa</td>
      <td>bu A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3">rabu</td>
      <td>fisika</td>
      <td>pak C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ekonomi</td>
      <td>bu B</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
      <td>sejarah</td>
      <td>bu C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="5">kamis</td>
      <td>kimia</td>
      <td>pak A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>akuntansi</td>
      <td>bu B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>pkn</td>
      <td>bu C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>pemrograman</td>
      <td>pak D</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>penjaskes</td>
      <td>bu E</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
<table>
```